# Groovy int vs integer function resolving

Tags: groovy

I recently started to learn Groovy and found not a natural behavior.

```
class BasicRouter {
    int method_(first){
        return 1;
    }
    int method_(int first){
        return 2;
    }
    int method_(short second){
        return 3;
    }
    int method_(Integer first){
        return 4;
    }
}
br = new BasicRouter()
int x = 1
assert br.method_(x) == 4
assert br.method_((int)29) == 2
```

Why in the first case we are passing a variable of type int, we get 4 and not 2?
I expect that method `int method_(int)` will be called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is here - http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-differences-java.html#_primitives_and_wrappers

*Groovy uses objects for everything*

This changes if you use CompileStatic

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic 
def fInt(int x) {new BasicRouter().method_(x)}
assert fInt(1) == 2
```

Comment: Thank you. It turns out the types int and Integer are only needed for CompileStatic? For a normal Groovy they always the same?

Comment: @BobSmelton, please consider accepting this as answer if that is helpful to you instead of just thank you.